# Update second value of all entry's in an array of tuples

Tags: java, arrays

i would like to update this array, the array represents 3x3 grid (1-9)

```
Shape[] shapeTransformed = new Shape[] {
            ( new Shape (1,'N') ),
            ( new Shape (2,'N') ),
            ( new Shape (3,'N') ),
            ( new Shape (4,'N') ),
            ( new Shape (5,'N') ),
            ( new Shape (6,'N') ),
            ( new Shape (7,'N') ),
            ( new Shape (8,'N') ),
            ( new Shape (9,'N') )
    };
```

i would like to change each 2nd value in tuple to a new CHAR, some will have different chars.

What is the best way to do this? i am a Javascript developer and all the things i thought would work are giving errors.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: If the chars are always the same and will always be the same, why are you storing them in individual objects?

Comment: They will change, i would like to know how update them to new values dynamically

Comment: _"All the things i thought would work are giving errors"_ What have you tried? What kind of errors are you seeing? If you provide further details, it'll be a lot easier to help you arrive at a working solution?

Comment: you have to iterate through the list, then

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
for (int row = 0; row < shapeTransformed.length; row++) {
        shapeTransformed[row].id = 'D';
}
```

Considering you have created the Shape class as,

```
class Shape {
    int id;
    char c;

    public Shape(int id, char c) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```